# "Open with" launched instead of "paste" when dropping a file into directory

Tags: windows-explorer

The Windows Explorer shows a list of files in the current dir. I want to drop one file more. Yet, all my files are executable and launched with dropped file as argument instead of move/copy/shortcut appearing. I understand that this inconvenience was done for my convenience. How do I workaround it? Where is the white space?

Comment: Can you rephrase that question?

Comment: "When I drop a file directly onto a program, it opens the file in that program" -- then don't do that.  Drop the file in the empty space.

Comment: My question is "WHERE IS THE EMPTY SPACE?"!!!

Comment: ***Empty space*** means the space below the list of files. If the file-list is ***full*** and all files are executable, you may find it difficult to find empty space to drop the additional file. In that case, drop it into the target folder in the folder-list on the left side of Windows Explorer.

Comment: Option 1: Keyboard shortcuts: Cut = `Ctrl + X` or Copy = `Ctrl + C` and paste = `Ctrl + V`; Option 2: Depending on what view your are in in Windows Explorer, usually to the far right side you can drop it and it's considered "white space".

Comment: @KevinFegan: the list cannot be full because there is not predefined list size limit. It is always extensible. Also, I hate locating my dir in the tree view panel. It might be a workaround but it is improper way of dropping the files into the panel I ask.

Comment: You can drop the file on the title bar of the destination folder window.

Comment: @Val - By ***full***, I mean the list of files fills or exceeds the size of the window, and scrolling the window does not reveal any empty space below the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can either drop the file into the empty space at the bottom of the explorer window (where the properties are shown) or,
2. You can drag it to the preferred folder in the folder list on the left hand side. 
   Cool Tip: You can actually right-click on an empty space in the folder list area and select "expand to current folder" instead of navigating to it using those little arrows

[image: pic]

Comment: How can I find the empty space in the folder list? Actually I want to disable this "cool tip" because I hate my folders view jumping unnecessarily.

Comment: @Val The empty space in the folder list is in between the folder groups, for example: in the above picture, empty space would be above and below Homegroup or parallel to the no.2 where i've right clicked. As for disabling the folders expanding, i googled around a bit but couldn't find anything, maybe you should uncheck "Expand to current folder" in the context menu above.

Comment: Your "cool feature" seems impossible to disable http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-disable-the-automatically-expand-to/566dd1f3-b105-48ea-9005-3715850f7e8d

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround would be to use keyboard shortcuts instead of DnD.

More appropriate answers are: find the space at the far right or target title bar on the top or status/properties at the bottom.

The answers were extracted from the comments.